# Why FindById returns Optional?

Tags: java, option-type

I'm currently overriding in my repository interface the `findById` to return a normal object because I don't like the unecessary code I have to do like: `.isPresent()` and `.get()`

```
ApplicationType findById(long applicationTypeId);
```

I just check `if(applicationType != null)`

Any reason why Optional is implemented here??

Comment: because one day after you quit your job and go to your dream trip to Costa Rica, a junior developer will write `findById(applicationTypeId).getSomething()`

Comment: can you be more specific? maybe show more source code

Comment: [Java 8 Optional: What's the Point?](https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-optional-whats-point) Search for more.

Comment: @OleV.V., the article is a poor example of usage of `Optional`.

Answer (score 3):

[Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) is implemented in JDK since JDK 8.

It humbly wants to avoid using the checks of null throught the code (just as you actually did)

`Optional` return here means we can either have an `ApplicationType` value or `null`.

When having an `Optional` you can check the value with `isPresent()`. The value of `Optional` can be fetched with `get()`

Optional are interesting especially when performing action directy with functions on the optinal itself with something alone with this :

```
Optional<ApplicationType> applicationType = repo.findById(1L);
applicationType.ifPresent(value -> doSomething(value));
applicationType.orElse(defaultApplicationType);
```

Here a complete [guide](https://www.baeldung.com/java-optional) on Optionals